# How to make separate CLI tools in docker containers accessible from "central "docker container?

Tags: docker, design-patterns, architecture, vps, orchestration

I want to create a tool that couples together a lot (~10, perhaps more) of other CLI tools to automate some stuff. This tool needs to be able to just be dropped-in on any VPS and work, hence the Docker containers. Work in this case means running central program (made by me) that orchestrates all the other tools and aggregates their results in a single database to browse/export later. The tools' containers need to have network access.

In my limited knowledge of Docker I've concluded that multi-stage build to fit all the tools in a single container is a bad design here, and very cumbersome. I've thought of networking the tools' containers to the central one and doing some sort of TCP piping, but that seems less than ideal too. What should the approach here be like? Are there some ready-made solutions to this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Can you use a general-purpose system-automation tool like Ansible or Salt Stack to install the tools you need on the target systems, without necessarily involving Docker?  Is this question more about programming, or about getting a batch of tools on to remote hosts you're administering?  (In which case [devops.se] or [sf] could be better places to ask.)

Comment: "Bad design" is a very subjective term, but the only real way for containers to interface with one another is via the network. Since that's not very straightforward for running CLI tools, my knee-jerk reaction is that your best bet is to build them all into one container. While many people preach that containers should be super tiny, have as little as possible; that's an opinion. A container is simply that - a container. What you put inside can be anything up to and including an entire Linux distribution; and doing exactly that is fairly common.

Comment: @DavidMaze The tools are primarily GitHub projects that require compilation with various dependencies. Since some of them already have their Docker images/Dockerfiles available I wanted to take advantage of that. As for the question's location, I couldn't decide that myself.

Comment: @DanLowe as I mentioned above, I wanted to take advantage of already existing Docker images/Dockerfiles. However you've somewhat calmed my fear of purists bashing me for creating a huge monster of a container, I might end up doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

How about [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)?

You can use this tool to deploy all your dockerized tools inside docker network and then communicate with them via your orchestrator. Additionally you can pack this composed dockers into another docker and create docker-in-docker environment and expose only your orchestrator as a gate to your all-in-one tool.

Cheers,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).